# Passing ID values with ajax in a secure way

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Imagine that I have a site where users' profile page has an address like below:

```
http://www.example.com/profile.php?p=123
```

Now I want to go to this profile and block (or another operation) this user when I click a button. I need to send the id of this user (123 in this case) to server with AJAX, and my question is, how can I send this id value to php server securely? (Currently I parse url parameters into a JSON object and pass them to server, but I don't know how secure this is.)

Comment: Use HTTPS/SSL to secure data sent over the network. If your information should not be publicly available, use login to authenticate a user, then use cookies to identify them and on the server side use a session to remember which user logged in. Then based on that information, decide what information the user can see. There are some nice tutorials out there on session handling.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is RSA encryption. You generate a key for your server to use which has a public version and a private version. Your javascript will contain the public version which can be used to encrypt the data, and your php will use the private version to decrypt the data.

As a jumping off point, you can start here for javascript public/private key examples: http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm

And here for the PHP side: http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/07/php-public-key-cryptography/

Comment: No. Use HTTPS to secure the connection. Don't roll your own stuff unless you know what you are doing.